# How can I assign dynamical values to refs in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

In [this ReactJS documentation on refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html), **myInput** is assigned to the input's ref.

```
<input ref="myInput" />
```

I have more than one input which I know only during the run time. I want to know how can I assign **myInput1**, **myImput2** to multiple inputs?

UPDATE:

I want to clarify on why I know the number of inputs only at run time.

I have a high order component which has an **input** control inside of that. The high order components can be many. They are created from an array of data. I want the **ref** to be set for the input inside that high order component so I can show some tooltip. There is only one tooltip in the DOM and positioned based on the input control's position.

Comment: how can you only know about your inputs during runtime are they bring rendered outside of react? right about the example you posted it says: Assign a ref attribute to anything returned from render such as:

Comment: Please see my update in the question.

Comment: thanks, thats much clearer now, you could use an index to add a ref to the input when you map, something like ref={'myInput+i'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it: you can dynamically add refs as you map over the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/vhuumox0/21/

```
class Main extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.refs); // works, shows 3
   console.log(this.refs.myInput2); // works
  }
  render() {
    const inputs = this.props.inputs.map((inp, i) => {
     return <input ref={`myInput${i}`}>{inp}</input>
    })
    return (
        <div>{inputs}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main inputs={['input1', 'input2', 'input3']}/>,
```